# ng-model for selectbox does not reflect changes in controller function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-options

I am having a problem with ng-model in select box using angularJs.
The model value is not updated in controller function. However, It does reflect the changes in controller when the select box is placed in the main template but not when it is placed in a directive template.

Works fine in main.html

```
<select ng-model="selectedGuest" id="guests-sel"
    ng-change="doSearchByFilterDropdown($event, selectedGuest.key, 'guests')" 
    ng-options="guest as guest.value for guest in guests track by guest.key">
 </select>
```

This is `main.html`

```
<div ng-init="init()">
    <div class="content-wrapper">

        <div ng-if="selTemplate == 'tourism'">
            <!-- Does not work reflect changes when changedin this directive template -->
            <search-results-tourism></search-results-tourism>
        </div>
        <!--  Select Box ng-model value reflects in controller when placed here, 
           but not in directive template -->
        <select ng-model="selectedGuest" id="guests-sel"  ng-change="doSearchByFilterDropdown($event, selectedGuest.key, 'guests')" 
           ng-options="guest as guest.value for guest in guests track by guest.key">
       </select> 

    </div>
</div>
```

Does not work in directive template. Earlier I was using ng-include for the template but I thought It was because of the new scope created by 
ng-include so I replaced it with a directive but still not working any Idea. ?

This is the directive

```
<search-results-tourism></search-results-tourism>
 ...
.directive('searchResultsTourism', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: false,
        templateUrl : 'views/search-results-tourism.html'
    };
```

Calling the same select box in directive's template does not let ng-model value updates in controller

Comment: what is the directive template and how are you setting/manipulating the selects data in the link function, how are you including the directive in the page?

Comment: Edited the details

Comment: I think it's a scope problem..  you can't reach selectedGuest in the parent  directive/controller

Comment: why don't you send an attribute to <search-results-tourism selected-guest="selectedGuest"></search-results-tourism>

Comment: The scope is of parent , see I have set scope: false . Why would be it a scope issue then. ?

Comment: do you initialize the 'selectedGuest' variable in the parent controller ?

Comment: an other possibility is that it doesn't work because of the ng-if

Comment: can you change it to ng-hide to test ?

Comment: ng-if removed , still the same

Comment: Thanks for help , btw

Comment: can you make a controller function in the directive and print what you receive from the scope ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

ng-if is creating a new scope for your directive.

from the documentation :

> Note that when an element is removed using ngIf its scope is destroyed and a new scope is created when the element is restored. The scope created within ngIf inherits from its parent scope using prototypal inheritance. An important implication of this is if ngModel is used within ngIf to bind to a javascript primitive defined in the parent scope. In this case any modifications made to the variable within the child scope will override (hide) the value in the parent scope.

Comment: Oh wait. I had other ng-if as well and you were absolutely right. It's because ng-if

Comment: Thanks a lot you saved my day